# How to write a method definition for a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures

I have a homework question that said:

Destructor_Helper is a recursive function that deallocates each node of singly linked list. Write a method definition for destructor_helper.

```
 struct Node
 {
      string data;
      Node *next;
 }

 void List::~List()  {
     destructor_helper(head);
 }
```

My answer was:

```
     void Destructor_Helper(Node *n) {
     cout<< n->data << endl;
     if (n->next != NULL)
          Destructor_Helper(n->next);
 }
```

My answer was counted wrong, would someone help me out to figure out the problem.

Comment: Hint: where are you de-allocating?

Comment: It doesn't actually delete anything.

Comment: so by adding "delete n;" the function will be corrrect?

Comment: Without delete, it cannot be correct. By adding delete, and doing things right, it will be correct. How to do it right, that's what the task is all about.

Comment: yes. Why don't you just try ? Take a pencil, draw a simple case with say 3 elements in the liked list and the solution will become obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are answer was counted wrong because you are not doing any deallocation.

To deallocate a linked list you can store the next node, deallocate the current and then go recursively on the next node. I would go like this:

```
void destructor_helper(Node *n) {
    if (n == NULL) return;
    Node* next = n->next;
    delete n;
    destructor_helper(next);
}
```

You can easily spot the *base case* of the recursion, which is when the current node is `NULL`. At that point we just need to return. Then, we store the next node in a local variable called `next` and we delete the current. The `next` local variable can be `NULL`, it doesn't matter. Then we pass `next` recursively to get the rest of the list deleted.

Comment: Would it matter to change it to void List::destructor_helper(Node *n)?

Comment: @user3467152, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

** SPOILER **

```
void Destructor_Helper(Node *n) {
    cout<< n->data << endl;
    if (n->next != NULL)
    {
        Destructor_Helper(n->next);
    }
    delete n;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: How about void List::Destructor_Helper(Node *n)

Comment: It doesn't matter for it to work. I just copied your method and added the `delete n;`. In fact Destructor_Helper() *should* be a method of List to encapsulate its functionality. So this matters for design.